# How do I urlencode in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, urlencode

How do I urlencode a url parameter in XSLT?

In php there is a function rawurlencode that does what I want, urlencode according to RFC 3986.

Comment: http://skew.org/xml/stylesheets/url-encode/url-encode.xsl

Answer (score 9, accepted):

XPath 2.0 (and hence XSLT 2.0) has the [`encode-for-uri` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-encode-for-uri).  I'm not aware of any way to do it in plain XPath 1.0/XSLT 1.0 without using extension functions.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use EXSLT's `str:encode-uri(., 'true', 'UTF-8')` in namespace `str=http://exslt.org/strings`

Most popular XSLT 1.0 processors solidly support EXSLT.